# Flutterfire web application error: undefiend

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter

I'm making my first Flutter + Firebase application, and I'm experiencing a strange error on the web app, when deployed on Firebase Hosting.
When I launch the application locally in Chrome browser there's no error and the app works perfectly.
The application is basically empty, it is the default counter app.

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem could be?

I tried removing all the Firebase services imports and dependencies, but nothing changed.

This is the error message shown in the JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught Error: undefined
    Z5 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:12944
    s https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5230
    $2 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:26828
    a4 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5216
    Z5 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:12970
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51052
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51046
    dartProgram https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51049
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51052
main.dart.js:3675:3
    a https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:3675
    $0 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:27400
    agx https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5378
    agI https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5380
    $1 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:26761
    ahu https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:3756
    s https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:3764
    (Async: MutationCallback)
    aeA https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5199
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:50913
    c https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:36
    a62 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5385
    nN https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5442
    m5 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:27034
    nn https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:26818
    a2 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5221
    Z5 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:12942
    s https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5230
    $2 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:26828
    a4 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:5216
    Z5 https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:12970
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51052
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51046
    dartProgram https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51049
    <anonymous> https://midika.web.app/main.dart.js:51052
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In the index.html file, the import of main.dart.js was before of all firebase imports.
Moving this import at the end of the file solved the problem.